# Returning an array from a JSX function and destructuring it elsewhere

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, destructuring

Experimenting a bit with JSX at the moment and came across this idea :

I can do this:

```
import React from 'react'

const Test = () => {    
  return <div>Test</div>
}
export default Test
```

and then import this file somewhere else and do:

```
<Test />
```

Why doesn't the same work if I return arrays from my JSX files?

```
import React from 'react'

const Test = () => {
  let arr = [
    <div>Test 1</div>,
    <div>Test 2</div>,
  ]
  return arr;
}
export default Test
```

and then:

```
let [firstElement, secondElement] = Test();

return ( 
  <div> 
    <firstElement /> 
  </div> 
 )
```

In both cases, what I am trying to render is a pretty plain `<div>`. In the first case it's returned directly, in the second case it's destructured from an array. However, the second case doesn't work for me? Should it?

PS: I know I could do `{firstElement}` - but why not `<firstElement />`?

Comment: No, I don't Think so

Comment: You don't show what the error message is. But an array on its own is not valid JSX, because it doesn't have a single "root" component. You could wrap the return value in a `Fragment` to make it valid, but then it's not an array so you can't destructure like that. JSX compiles to calls to `React.createElement`,and you should think of the result of that as an opaque data structure which represents your rendered output.

Comment: But am I not just dealing with a standard javascript function here? I am not trying to render an array as JSX, (which isn't valid JSX). I have a plain javascript function that returns an array with JSX items and then I try to render one of those - so shuldn't that still be valid JSX then? Or am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: @userjmillohara - sorry, you're right, I think I misread what your code was doing. So what do you mean by "doesn't work"? What's the error message, and which line in which file does it point to?

Comment: Oh I see now, `firstElement` is simply JSX, a React component needs to be a *function* (or class) that *returns* JSX

Comment: @RobinZigmond Exactly, I forgot to wrap them in functions! :( Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work:

```
  let arr = [
    () => <div>Test 1</div>,
    () => <div>Test 2</div>,
  ]
```

---

What you're doing currently is calling `React.createElement` twice.

First you call it inside the array (`<div>Test 1</div`), then you return the already created element from the function, and then you render it again, by calling `<firstElement/>`.

---

Side note, `firstElement` should be uppercase, or else (*I think*) the JSX transformer will consider it a native DOM element, rather than your custom component, which will result in a throw later).

Therefore either change what's in the array into components, as stated above (`() => <div>Test 1</div>`), or change `<firstElement />` into `{firstElement}`

---

Either way, what you're doing is quite hacky and shouldn't be anything more than a curiosity. `Test` should be coded as:

```
const Test = () => {
  const arr = [
    <div>Test 1</div>,
    <div>Test 2</div>,
  ];
  return <>{arr}</>;
}
```

Comment: I could've sworn that I had tried this too, just a minute ago, and it didn't work. But just tried again, and I must've missed something the first time, because this did the trick! Thanks a lot for this answer!

Comment: but wouldn't  `<>{arr}</>` simply render all items in the array? The reason I am experimenting with this is, because I had this idea of creating a component that returns (via destructuring) different components that are connected but that the parent component can then use in different places. not sure if this is a good idea of this would even work, quite new to this. Not good practice though?

Comment: @userjmillohara You're correct, it would simply render them in the array.

Comment: @userjmillohara I haven't seen such a pattern anywhere and it very strongly feels like an anti-pattern. Why do you want to do such a thing? How are these components 'connected'? You cannot use `useState` or any other hooks inside `Test`.

Comment: Does react unpack/iterate over an array and return its elements when you do something like this: `<p>foo</p> { [1,2,3,4,5] }`?
@JohnSmith

Comment: @Robert No, it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

The two divs are already react elements, an object created by React, and not components. To render them use an expression (curly braces):

```js
const test = () => [
  <div>Test 1</div>,
  <div>Test 2</div>,
]

const [firstElement, secondElement] = test();

const Demo = () => (
  <div> 
    {firstElement}
  </div> 
)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I mention in my question that I am aware I can do this, and that I'd like them to be JSX components. Thanks anyways though!